# Input not showing double quote in its value

Tags: html, input

I'm trying to set this value to an input: `10" Test"` which currently shows only `10`. When i removed the quote that is inside the output is `10 Test`

How can i show the correct value? i.e. `10" Test"`

Comment: It is hard to understand since the English is very broken, please fix it if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is how to escape the double quote character `"`.

The thing is that the double quote next to `10` is being interpreted as the attribute value closing quote thus breaking the value you want to set `10" Test`

> < input type=**"text"** value=**"10"** *Test"* >

If you're writing it directly in your html input value attribute you should use `&quot;` instead of `"`

For example:

```html
<input type="text" value="10&quot; Test&quot;" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I edited. Please help me again. Thanks.

Comment: Wherever you want to use the char `"` **as a value** in an input in your HTML  use `&quot;` instead. In your particular case: `<input type="text" value="10&quot; Test&quot;" />`

Comment: Consider that double quotes are attribute value delimiters in an HTML document. So, if you want to use that character as a value you should escape it: `&quot;`

Comment: It is ok. Thank you so much!